# How to write script for table filtering

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, filter

I'm fairly new in web design/code and I'm trying to figure out/learn how to write script that would execute my table filter. As I found out this would be easiest to do in PHP since all data comes from table itself (and not MySQL DB).

Here is example of HTML with test table and some filters I would like to implement, but I've been having problem with writing PHP script which would work properly.

http://www.bonemachineonline.com/test
(I uploaded example on my own site)

I would appreciate if someone could help me out with this in anyway! Writing example or explaining how/what to do. Anything is more than appreciate!

Comment: check out http://tablesorter.com/docs/ , a nice plugin to sort the table client side

Comment: If you don't need to re-invent the wheel, the [SlickGrid](https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid) is an easily programmable data grid that you can use as a base and customize how you like

Comment: try looking at jqgrid , or if you like some Javascript , look into any of frameworks like ExtJS , Knockout.js , Angular.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 3 approaches for data filtering.

If the table is filtered by default, and all the data are not loaded, take the **(1)** or **(2)**.

If you load the whole table each time, take the **(3)**.

---

## Approaches

**(1)** Server side, with page reloading : your user checks filters, then clicks on a submit button. You get all the checked filters and you send it to your PHP. Server side, you retrieve the filters and remake your query (SQL or other in your case).

**(2)** Server side, with [AJAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29) : exactly the same mechanism, but you send the filters to your PHP with an AJAX request, wait a response, remove your table and remake a table with the new data.

**(3)** Client side, with JavaScript only : when your user checks a filter, you trigger the change event and hide the matched elements in the table.

---

## Some tips

For the approaches **(2)** and **(3)**, [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) could be very useful.

For the approach **(3)**, you can use a library. Here: [35+ Useful jQuery Filter and Sort Plugins](http://www.tripwiremagazine.com/2013/06/jquery-filter-sort-plugins.html).

For the approach **(1)**, if in your case the data are in a PHP array, you have a lot of functions to manipulate this array in function of your filters. Here: [Array Functions - Table of Contents](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.array.php).

Answer (score 1):

Try using jquery `dataTable()`.
You can refer the below link

[Jquery-dataTable()](http://jquery-datatables-column-filter.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/customFilters.html)